# How to store the EditText style (Bold, Italic, Color, etc.) using Sharedpreferences

Tags: android, android-edittext, styles, sharedpreferences, store

Please anyone tell me
How to save `text selected` in the `EditText` by (Bold, Italic, Color, etc.) using **SharedPreferences**.

**Here is my code:**

```
int selectionStart = editTxt.getSelectionStart();    
int selectionEnd = editTxt.getSelectionEnd();                                
SpannableStringBuilder  stringBuilder = (SpannableStringBuilder) editTxt.getText();   
TextAppearanceSpan styleRed_Bold = new TextAppearanceSpan(getBaseContext(), R.style.CustomStyle);                                             stringBuilder.setSpan(styleRed_Bold , selectionStart , selectionEnd , 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); 

Editor editor = pref.edit();

editor.putString("edittext", "text of your edit text"); 

editor.putString("style", "bold"); 

editor.apply
```

Comment: How he knows selected text is bold.. not italic or regular ?

Comment: @AliAhmed its another question

Comment: please give me up vote to become 0 , don't know why people give me negative vote

Comment: I didn't give you negative.

Comment: @AliAhmed i know , you tell that before , but you can give me up vote to become this to zero

Comment: I will store style of `selected text` in `Bold, italic or color` and `save changes with text` ...          thankyou